# How to import json file in google classroom apis

Tags: python, api, google-classroom

I have one JSON file which has MCQs. It has fields like questioned, questions, options, and answers. These are in JSON format. Now I want to create an assignment and import this file. But I don't know how to do it. I have read the below link but I am not getting any idea.

https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-classwork

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do read the guidelines for posting questions. as a rule, post data samples and code of what you've tried yourself. Do not expect the community to code for you. It is there to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an assignment, you will have to make the following request:

```
POST https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWork
```

With the following request body - which is essentially the `CourseWork` resource:

```
{
  "courseId": string,
  "id": string,
  "title": string,
  "description": string,
  // other fields
}
```

However, if you want to pass your own JSON, you have to make sure that this complies with the format of the [`CourseWork`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#resource:-coursework) resource.

#### Reference

- [Classroom API CourseWork Resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#CourseWork).